# Firestoreb collection foreach loop returns empty id

Tags: javascript, angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

in my collection (Campaign), I want to return a specific document id by a campaignName

this is my method :

```
getCampaignId(): string {
    const campaignCollection = this.afs
      .collection<Campaign>('mail_campaign')
      .snapshotChanges();

    campaignCollection.forEach((value) => {
      return value.map((res) => {
        if (res.payload.doc.data().campaignName === 'x') {
          this.campaignId = res.payload.doc.id;
        }
        return '';
      });
    });
    return this.campaignId;
  }
```

inside the **`if`** , I get the id if I print it directly in the console :

```
console.log(res.payload.doc.id);
```

but if I print my global variable `this.campaignId` in the constructor, I get an empty string (the method is called in the constructor before printing the variable in the console)

I want to use this variable outside of this class, but I can't because it's returning an empty string.

Any ideas ?